# Custom Excel formula issue OR Statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out a formula for the duration of an investigative case based on the assigned date. So far I am able to do that. Once the closure date is entered the duration stops and a dash is entered (eventually going to try to incorporate a formula that captures the final duration before the case closure date was entered). What happens next is if you look at row 18 when the date assigned is blank and the closure date is blank it still calculates. I can’t figure out how to incorporate that if the date assigned is blank only show as a dash into the formula.

I have tried many varied combinations included nested ifs but have not been successful.

Here is the formula:

```
=IF(OR([@[Closure Date]]="", [@[Date Assigned]]=""),NETWORKDAYS([@[Date Assigned]],TODAY(),Duration!$A$2:$A$12),"-")
```

Here is what the sheet looks like:

[image]

Comment: change `OR([@[Closure Date]]="", [@[Date Assigned]]="")` to `AND([@[Closure Date]]="", [@[Date Assigned]]<>"")`

Comment: You were correct sometimes it’s so simple I’ve been at this for two days. Thank you so much.